# Curious integral

Tags: integration

I am interested in computing a rather nasty integral of the following form:

$$
4\int_0^x 
\mathrm{d}\theta \frac{2|l_m\cos(\theta-\theta_m)|\log|l_m\cos(\theta-\theta_m)|-\sum_{j\in\{1,2,3\}}|l_j\cos(\theta-\theta_j)|\log|l_j\cos(\theta-\theta_j)|}{\prod_{j\in\{1,2,3\}}|l_j\cos(\theta-\theta_j)|}
$$

where $m=\mathrm{argmax}_{m\in\{1,2,3\}}|l_m\cos(\theta-\theta_m)|$.

Curiously, when integrated to $x=2\pi$, this integral yields $\frac{(2\pi)^2}{A}$, where $A$ is the area of the triangle with angles $\theta_{1,2,3}$ and sides $l_{1,2,3}$ (assuming a valid triangle and verified numerically). Any clues on how to approach this analytically, for any $x\leq2\pi$?

Comment: What do you mean by area of a triangle with angles $\theta_{1,2,3}$ ?

Comment: We may assume that the thetas add up to 180 degrees, then A is the area of the triangle with angles theta_{1,2,3}.

Comment: Angles alone can't define the area of a triangle, how are you normalizing the side lengths?

Comment: Oh bad copy, of course, editted.